# Running Spring boot fat JAR

Tags: spring-boot, uberjar

```html
C:\Users\sinpik\Desktop\jar\extract>java -jar PackageProject-client.jar
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at PachName.Application.main(Application.java:14)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:168)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

I have created a sample application in Spring Boot and it is running properly in IDE. I want to package it as a fat JAR and run it through command prompt. How do I do it? I am running it using  `java -jar JarName.jar`.
This is my build script:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.1.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'eu.appsatori:gradle-fatjar-plugin:0.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'eu.appsatori.fatjar'

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}


fatJar{
    manifest {
     attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
    //      'Implementation-Version': version,
        'Main-Class': 'PachName.Application'
     }

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}

fatJarPrepareFiles {
    include 'application.properties'

  }

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? It doesn't work?

Comment: You don't need to use the fat jar plugin. The Spring Boot plugin will take care of that for you

Comment: just creating a fat wont give me all jar file. so i used fatJAR